# Multivariate Bayesian formula

Tags: machine-learning, probability, self-study, proof

I got there example  graphs bishop's PRML (8.2.1)
1. **a <- c -> b**
$$
p(a,b,c) = p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c)    --(1)\\
p(a,b) = \sum_c p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c)   --(2)
$$ 
**Q1**: Can I use a new graph to represent the p(a,b) in formula (2) ?

2.**a->c->b**
$$
p(a,b,c) = p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)--(3)\\  
p(a,b) = p(a)\sum_c{p(c|a)p(b|c)} = p(a)p(b|a)  --(4)
$$
**Q2**: $$\sum_c{p(c|a)p(b|c)} = \sum_c{p(b,c|a)} ? why$$

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the `self-study` tag since this seems to be unambiguously a textbook question. Please see the [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Is there any information/condition missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, you may see the result of this formula by drawing the corresponding graph as follows:

[image: p(c|a)p(b|c)]

The joint distribution represented by this graph is given by p(c|a)p(b|c)p(a). Now, summing out c, can be interpreted as removing the node labeled with c from the graph. So, the resulting graph is:

[image]

This new graph has the following joint distribution p(b|a)p(a).

Regarding a mathemtical view of Q2, we should note first that the book refers specifically at the graph a->c->b (Figure 8.17 in Bishop's Book) when talking about the equation in Q2.

p(b,c|a) = p(a, b, c)/p(a) "Definition of conditional probability"

p(b,c|a) = [p(b|c)p(c|a)p(a)]/p(a) "From the graph a->c->b we get the joint distribution"

p(b,c|a) = p(b|c)p(c|a) "Cancelling p(a) out"

Now, ∑<sub>c</sub>p(c|a)p(b|c)=∑<sub>c</sub>p(b,c|a)

∑<sub>c</sub>p(b,c|a) = p(b|a) "[marginalization rule of probability](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de%2Fteaching%2Fss10%2Frobotics%2Fetc%2Fprobability-rules.pdf&ei=2fzkU-nxFrCL4gSh5IHoDA&usg=AFQjCNEkPusZZPWAOwXviG-7OvoMUzYL8w&bvm=bv.72676100,d.bGE)"

I hope these steps make it clearer now.

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed proof based on chain rule. I can't factorize it. Because it is a conditional probablity. And how to explain $\sum_c{p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c)}$ based on the graph way

Comment: I may refer first to the @user52705 comment. In ∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c), both a and b are conditioned over c and thus, c cannot be summed out in a straight forward manner. In this case, if you draw the graph and try to remove c, someone will be confused on how to orient the edge direction between a and b i.e. is it a->b or b->a.

∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c) = ∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(c|b) "using Bayes rule"

∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(c|b) = p(a|b). So, the resulted graph is b->a

Comment: In summary, the graph representation here is limited in certain cases like when all variables are conditioned on a single variable and we want to remove this variable. In such cases, we need to discover the correct re-orientation of edges' directions between the variables. If we, however, can do some kind of transformation using Bayes rule as I did in the example, we may infer the new relationship in an easier way.

Keep in mind that in graph representation, all the following are equivalent and can be proved using Bayes rule:

a -> c -> b
,a -> c <- b
,a <- c <- b

Comment: For the chain rule, thanks for asking for more detailed steps as it turns out I had a mistake before the edit in the above answer.

Comment: why "∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c) = ∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(c|b) "? what do you mean the there graphs are equivalent（They all equal to p(a,b,c)?）.  I have refined my questions. Can you help my to review it.

Comment: ∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c) = ∑<sub>c</sub>p(a|c)p(c|b) because p(b|c) = p(c|b)/P(c) "Bayes rule". It is not that they are all equal to p(a,b,c) but that the p(a,b,c) i.e. the joint probability of each is equal to the other ones
Can you give me the page again in Bishop's book for Q2?

Comment: 1. p(b|c)/p(b) = p(c|b)/P(c) not p(b|c) = p(c|b)/P(c) right? 2.page 374  formula after (8.26)

Comment: Check my updated answer now !

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to multiply with $p(a)$ to LHS side of your equation the summation actually results in $p(b/a)$. I would suggest you to recheck the equation in the book.

Comment: Yes. I made a mistake. How to prove the formula?

Comment: As @soufanom has given the intuition behind the chain rule. And the way i see it , you have applied it wrongly i.e in your equation $∑_c p(a|c)p(b|c)p(c)$. Actually according to the graph c is conditional over a and not the other way round and similarly b is conditional over c. I am not sure whether proof exists for chain rule. It has to be derived empirically or to be proven by induction.